# WooCommerce searchable drop down list

Tags: php, html, jquery, woocommerce

so I've implemented a billing form with some custom fields , my drop down is :

```
$fields['billing_complex_name'] = array(
         'label' => __('Complex Name', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('E.g Raslouw Gardens', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'select',// add field type
          'options'     => array(
         '' => 'Please select',
                         'ansaarestate'=> 'Ansaar Estate',
              'bangladeshheights'=> 'Bangladesh Heights',
                        'celticmanor'=> 'Celtic Manor',
                        'chantelplace'=> 'Chantel Place',
             ... 
        'class' => array('my-css'),
          'priority' => 51,// 
   );
```

And then using jQuery I implement the following for changes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code in here
  jQuery(document).on('input','#billing_complex_name', function() {
 
      myFunc();
})
function myFunc() {
    // your function code
//var phone_num = jQuery('#billing_phone').val(<?php $phone_number ?>);

    
var complex_name = jQuery('#billing_complex_name').val();

var suburb = jQuery('#billing_suburb').val();

if (complex_name == 'eldogleneast') {
   jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('ELD');
   jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0157');
    jQuery("#billing_complex_address").val('');
jQuery("#billing_postcode").prop("readonly", false);
```

And of course depending on the selection of the complex conditions change such as the postcode or suburb etc.
My question now is:
I need to make the drop down list searchable and have an Other selection , if Other is selected I need a text input for the user to enter in and that will be the selected value (All jQuery then will just not make any changes to the postcode or anything)

Answer (score 0):

Used select2.js library to implement it